# Is there a reason why the tag "slackware" cannot be edited?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Normally, when looking at tag information, at the bottom of the screen, there is a button labeled "Edit Tag Info".

However, when looking at [slackware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/slackware) today, there is no way to suggest edits.

Problem is pictured below:

[image]

Info page in question:

https://superuser.com/tags/slackware/info

Comment: Good question. When I checked the tags I only saw a few `edit` links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the edit history, the post was deleted "by the community":

[image: deleted]

I guess you can't edit a tag wiki that has been deleted.

Turns out what happened here was that the original wiki was suggested by a user who was later destroyed for engaging in nefarious behavior; in these situations *all* posts owned by the user are deleted along with them - including, as it turns out, tag wikis or tag excerpts (the first editor gets implicit ownership of the "post" that backs these wikis).

There were three other such tags scattered around the network; all are now fixed and can be edited.

Comment: As a <10k user, when I try to click the "edit history" link, I am presented with a 404 error, which is typical for deleted posts. However, even though the post is deleted, it still shows up in the main "Tags" when searching.

Comment: Yeah, the *tag* is fine; the *wiki* is what got deleted. This is a pretty unusual situation; the system doesn't even allow undeleting tag wikis. I had to do a little dance with tag merges to ditch the old history.

Comment: Oh, uh... I inadvertently gave myself a taxonomist badge fixing this. If anyone more deserving wants it, lemme know.